# How to get Date Picker Date Time with Country/Zone Time Wise

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, timezone

If my device's date is changed from device settings, my app's date  can  changed. I want the app to display the date according to the international time zone if the user device changes the default date but does not change the date in the app.
For example : My Country is Bangladesh and Time Zone : GMT+6.

(I want my date picker date show international date can't depend on device default date format.)

My Code is Here :

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MyActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    c.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    String dateString = format.format(c.getTime());

                    tDate.setText(dateString);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: I believe that the best solution will be to find a date picker component that supports `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). A `LocalDate` is a calendar date without time or time zone.

Comment: In any case you should consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API to which `LocalDate` belongs. It is so much nicer to work with.